# How to extract table from php site to R data frame

Tags: php, r, dataframe

How to parse or extract the table from the php into a dataframe. I only need to see the table

I tried this

```
theurl <- "http://www.medindex.am/glossary/semantic_types/B2.2-disease-syndrome-pathologic-function.php"
doc <- htmlParse(GET(theurl, user_agent("Mozilla")))
results <- xpathSApply(doc, "//*/table[@id='table_results_r_1']")
results <- readHTMLTable(results[[1]])
rm(doc)
```

It doesn't work as a failed attempt

http://www.medindex.am/glossary/semantic_types/B2.2-disease-syndrome-pathologic-function.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is not dynamically rendered or added through additional xhr requests. You don't need the expense of a browser. Simply use httr with an user-agent header (as the server checks for this) and then the following css selector, as below, to target the right table:

```
library(httr)
library(magrittr)

r <- httr::GET(
  url = "http://www.medindex.am/glossary/semantic_types/B2.2-disease-syndrome-pathologic-function.php",
  httr::add_headers(.headers = c("user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))
) %>%
  content()

r %>%
  html_element("p + table") %>%
  html_table()
```

Comment: thank you for another way of solving the problem

Answer (score 2):

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

#setup driver, client and server
driver <- rsDriver( browser = "firefox", port = 4545L, verbose = FALSE ) 
server <- driver$server
browser <- driver$client

#goto url in browser
browser$navigate("http://www.medindex.am/glossary/semantic_types/B2.2-disease-syndrome-pathologic-function.php")

#get all tables
doc <- xml2::read_html(browser$getPageSource()[[1]])
all.table <- rvest::html_table(doc)

#close everything down properly
browser$close()
server$stop()
# needed, else the port 4545 stays occupied by the java process
system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern = FALSE, ignore.stdout = FALSE)

all.table[[2]]
> all.table[[2]]
# A tibble: 22,397 x 4
# CUI      Term                              Dictionary SemanticType                 
# <chr>    <chr>                             <chr>      <chr>                        
# 1 C0003865 Arthritis, Adjuvant               NDFRT      Experimental Model of Disease
# 2 C0004426 avian sarcoma                     CSP        Experimental Model of Disease
# 3 C0004565 B16 Malignant Melanoma            NCI        Experimental Model of Disease
# 4 C0007098 Carcinoma 256, Walker             NDFRT      Experimental Model of Disease
# 5 C0007125 Carcinoma, Ehrlich Tumor          NDFRT      Experimental Model of Disease
# 6 C0007128 Carcinoma, Krebs 2                NDFRT      Experimental Model of Disease
# 7 C0009075 Cloudman S91 Malignant Melanoma   NCI        Experimental Model of Disease
# 8 C0011853 Diabetes Mellitus, Experimental   NDFRT      Experimental Model of Disease
# 9 C0014072 autoimmune encephalomyelitis      CSP        Experimental Model of Disease
# 10 C0018598 Harding-Passey Malignant Melanoma NCI        Experimental Model of Disease
```

Comment: Thank you very much although  i did read about RSelenium i was not sure how to put it into action

Comment: "system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern = FALSE, ignore.stdout = FALSE) do i need to run this as im running R on Cent OS

Comment: nope.. that is for windows to close the java process properly.

Comment: on centos you could use `netstat` in the commant prompt to see if the port is still open after closing the browser..

Comment: Error in (function (platform, file, processed, chmod)  : 
  ~/.local/share/binman_geckodriver/linux64/0.30.0/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz.asc does not appear to be a zip or tar file. i guess i have to run in windows

Comment: i guess... I dow not have a *nix system running at the time, so the solution above is only tested on windows. Rselenium should run fine on *nix systems, but might need some additional setup/packages..

Comment: no issue i will run it on windows now